# Why is VS2013 load testing only running 7 requests per second?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, load-testing, performance-testing

I am running some load tests, and for some reason VS is displaying as 7 req/sec, is this normal?

I have a stepped profile, starting at 10, ending at 100, and I would have thought it would run the test for each user.

I.e - 10 users, 10 requests per second?

[image]

Comment: If you get a disappointing outcome from a load test then the first assumption you do *not* make that there is something wrong with the test tool.  Use a profiler next.

Comment: Load testing will produce a host of values. Look at them collectively to determine what is happening. I think we cannot give useful advice when you only give one summary value. Given only 243 tests were executed but you say the user load is stepped, I wonder what was happening.

Answer (score 3):

First, you're running load testing from your local machine (Controller = Local Run). You can run load tests from your developer machine, but you usually can't generate enough traffic to really see how the application responds. To simulate a lot of users, you need a Load Test Rig.  (on Premises, or using Windows Azure Cloud Testing). This can be a problem especially, if you're testing a web site hosted on the same computer.
Check the CPU on your machine when running the load test (in the graph) : if it's over 70%, results are biaised.

Second, how do you recorded web tests ? when using web test recorder (in IE), it will add a think time to each request. Think times are used to simulate human behavior that causes people to wait between interactions with a Web site : a real user will never open 4 pages in the same second. You can check Think Time in each request properties. A high value may explain why you've only a few requests/sec if the CPU is still low.

> I have a stepped profile, starting at 10, ending at 100, and I would
>   have thought it would run the test for each user.

In Run settings, you have the option to configure the maximum number of iterations : this will run N scenarios, without any time limit. It's not activated by default.

You have to understand the notion of virtual user : Basically, a virtual user executes concurrently only one test case at the same time, taken from configured web tests, according to test mix/percentage/sceanrios... So 10 concurrent virtual users, will execute at most 10 tests at the same time. The Step goal is usually used to increase the load until the server reaches a point that where performance diminishes significantly.
A complete description of all Load Patterns are available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997551.aspx).

At end, if the number of request/sec is still low, and if it's not because of Load Testing configuration, you may have a problem on your web site ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your test configuration, but if your test is setup to do ~1 req/s with one user it should deliver ~10 req/s with 10 users.

I would say that it's probably because your server can't handle responding with more than 7 req/s. To find out where the bottle neck is try to run smaller steps and see where the breaking point is, you can do some monitoring on the servers at the same time to find out what resources are running out and on which server (CPU, mem, bw etc). Like mentioned in the comments profiling is a very good approach to find out what parts of the code and which queries is the resource hog.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of reasons throughput could be low.
Check your settings for "Think Time Between Test Iterations", step load pattern - step duration is another setting you could modify. 
Remember to keep the test moving so looking at think times for each request and making sure you are not taking too long to perform each test end to end.
I have seen where these settings can extend the overall time to more that a few minutes thus reducing the minute by minute transactions.
Check your end to end run time per webtest if run independent from the load test to make sure you know how much time the test takes overall. 
Hope this helps.
 - Jim Nye